# How to prevent switching app or locking screen from terminating current WhatsApp working task?

Tags: ios, performance

The problem is like this:

1. When I open Whatsapp
2. Select an attachment in a conversation
3. Forward this attachment using "Share" button sharing to Google Drive app
4. Select the destination
5. Waiting to finish.

If I have initiated the forwarding action with a lot of files, I need to wait until the whole process is completed. Or if the screen go is locked automatically or switching to other app, any action leaving the current working screen will trigger the Whatsapp back to step 3. Is it unavoidable in iPhone? Is it Whatsapp development problem or iPhone built-in limitation?

Answer (score 0):

As a consumer, you can't control this behavior as it's up to the WhatsApp team to program background uploads and resumption of an interrupted process according to how Apple makes their API and SDK.

If you can't indirectly affect this by moving to a faster network (assuming your network is the slow factor - it could be whats app constraint on the server receiving your upload that's causing that to time out) or choose smaller attachments, this is understandable side effect of how iOS handles background tasks and app switching.

Many other apps do this well, so it's not limited by iOS and there are servers capable of getting large attachments uploaded to a conversation once you initiate it without you having to take positive action. These apps do require careful engineering and spending enough on the infrastructure to enable this. I could see WhatsApp deciding they don't make enough money on storing attachments to let this be a pain point for things larger than a short image / gif / emoji.

- How large an upload of documents are you attaching?
- How long does it take to save them and upload them to iCloud or OneDrive or another high performing file sync app?